# JSTL if-statement inside HTML-attribute

Tags: css, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

is it possible to do something like this in JSTL:

```
<div class="firstclass<c:if test='true'> someclass</c:if>">
   <p>some other stuff...</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get this to work, or is there a better way to add a class by looking at a JSTL-if-statement?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It's also possible to use an EL expression directly like this:

```
<div class="${booleanExpr ? 'cssClass' : 'otherCssClass'}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 43):

```
<c:if test='true'> 
  <c:set value="someclass" var="cssClass"></c:set>
</c:if> 
<div class="${cssClass}">
   <p>some other stuff...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the following worked in combination with Java:

```
<%
String cssClass = 'oneClass';

if(i >= 5){
   cssClass += " anotherClass";
}

<div cssClass="<%= cssClass %>" >... </div>
%>
```

Answer (score -4):

That works for me!

```
<div id="loginById" style="height:<% out.print(instanceClass.booleanMethod()? "250px": "150px");%>">
```